# Is $x$ not actually equal to $e^{\ln(x)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

Yeah, this is a silly question, but I can't seem to convince myself that the graph $f(x)=x$ is really equal to the graph of $g(x)=e^{\ln(x)}$. Specifically, doesn't this fail on negative values of $x$? Since $g(x)$ is not defined on negative values of $x$, I don't see how these two could be equal. How could I remedy $g(x)$ without using piecewise functions to make these functions have the same domain?

Comment: You don't need to do logarithms to see the problem with $x^x$ when $x$ is negative. For example, when $x=-1/2$, you get $$x^x=\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^{-1/2}=(-2)^{1/2}=\sqrt{-2}.$$ So you can only do $x^x$ when $x$ is negative if you allow complex values, and then things get complicated. So you can only really define $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} x^x.$

Comment: This is very enlightening! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you allow real or complex values for the functions.  As other answers point out, if only real values are allowed then $x$ must be positive.  If complex values are allowed, then a real value of $x$ might also be negative, and the identity also holds for non-real values of $x$; this is valid for all branches of the logarithm.

BUT ... it is never possible to define any logarithm of zero, therefore even in the more flexible complex case $x\ne 0$ is required.

Comment: One can define $\ln 0=-\infty$, and this works well on the extended real line.

Answer (score 5):

It happens that $\log$ is a map from $(0,+\infty)$ onto $\mathbb R$ and that $\exp$ is a map from $\mathbb R$ onto $(0,+\infty)$. So, the equality $\exp\bigl(\log(x)\bigr)=x$ only has to be true (and *it is* true) when $x\in(0,+\infty)$).

Comment: Okay, perhaps I should explain my motivation for asking. I'm attempting to solve the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} x^x$. After a couple steps, we realize this is equal to $\exp[\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(x)}{1/x}]$. However, It is my understanding that neither $\lim_{x\to 0} \ln(x)$ nor $\lim_{x\to 0} 1/x$ is defined. However, graphically, we know that $\lim_{x\to 0}x^x$ exists and is equal to 1. Perhaps this is a problem I have to evaluate from the right and left of 0?

Comment: @BlakeSplitter $x^x$ was defined only for $x>0$, and the definition was $e^{x\ln(x)}$. And the next step you are missing is to use L'Hospital on the limit inside the exponential.

Comment: Why can't it be defined for negative values? Isn't ${(-5)}^{-5}$ defined?

Comment: Yes, but in introductory courses of calculus over the reals it is left defined just at the positives. At the negatives you need to stat taking into account that $ln$ is a multivalued function.

Comment: Ah, so in other words, $\lim_{x\to 0} x^x$ is defined, but the tools to prove this don't exist until much later in the mathematics sequence?

Comment: @BlakeSplitter I wasn't talking about whether the limit is defined or not, I was talking about where $x^x$ is defined in introductory real calculus books/courses. Carefully written books and courses would make clear what is their definition of $x^x$ and in particular its domain.

Answer (score 1):

The equality $x=e^{\ln(x)}$ holds indeed only for $x>0$.

The piecewise version could be

- for $x>0$ $g(x)=e^{\ln(x)}$
- for $x<0$ $g(x)=-e^{\ln(|x|)}$
- for $x=0$ $g(x)=0$